# Python - Kivy - pyInstaller - Gerar executáveis

Tags: python, kivy

Bom dia pessoal.

Estou com um projeto kivy onde estou trabalhando com, ou pelo menos tentando trabalhar no modo MVC.
Desse modo, tenho as pastas view, model, controller. Na pasta view tenho os arquivos ".kv" do kivy.

O problema e minha dúvida é: 
Como usar o pyinstaller para gerar um executável nesse caso?
Já tentei utilizar normalmente como quando é desenvolvido tudo em um único arquivo mas não funciona.

Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,
Passei pelo mesmo problema, encontrei solução no site da biblioteca Kivy ([kivy.org](https://kivy.org))

Ocorre que atualmente, quando geramos o executável através do pyinstaller, ele não carrega o arquivo .kv automaticamente (se este arquivo estiver na mesma pasta do seu código principal).

Um meio de contornar isso é informar ao PyInstaller que quer empacotar este aquivo .kv também. Pra mim funcionou assim:

> > Coloque seu arquivo .kv em um pasta, que fique dentro da pasta onde já está seu arquivo principal (pra facilitar)
> >
> > Se o pyinstaller está instalado, no CMD você consegue gerar um arquivo .spec com o seguinte comando: `pyi-makespec nome_do_seu_arquivo.py`;
> >
> > Este terá as especificações do que está sendo feito pelo PyInstaller;
> >
> > Abra o arquivo .spec (pode ser com o bloco de notas);
> >
> > Vá em '**COLLECT**' e após **exe,** escreva **Tree('Nome_da_pasta_onde_esta_seu_arquivo_kv\'),**
> >
> > Obs.: Não se esqueça da vírgula

Diz pra gente se funcionou.